# Why doesn't the code "horizontal loop scroll" work on a real browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am supposed to make a component which is horizontal loop scroll in both direction.

It is perfectly fine on Codepen but not on a real browser when I put them in a single HTML file. It works fine in up direction but in down direction.

I have tried this on several browsers but the results are the same.

You can see the full source code here:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="pane">
        <div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <div>Last</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:200%;
}
#page {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#CCC;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
}
.pane {
  flex:0 0 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}

.pane:nth-child(4n+2)  {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}
.pane:nth-child(4n+3)  {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}
.pane:nth-child(4n+4)  {
  background-color: #E84B30;
}
.pane:last-child {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var page = document.getElementById('page');
var last_pane = page.getElementsByClassName('pane');
last_pane = last_pane[last_pane.length-1];
var dummy_x = null;

window.onscroll = function () {
  // Horizontal Scroll.
  var y = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  page.scrollLeft = -y;

  // Looping Scroll.
  var diff = window.scrollY - dummy_x;
  if (diff > 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, diff);
  }
  else if (window.scrollY == 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, dummy_x);
  }
}
// Adjust the body height if the window resizes.
window.onresize = resize;
// Initial resize.
resize();

// Reset window-based vars
function resize() {
  var w = page.scrollWidth-window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight;
  document.body.style.height = w + 'px';

  dummy_x = last_pane.getBoundingClientRect().left+window.scrollY;
}
```

```
It is supposed to work fine on any browsers.
```

Comment: That's not a valid HTML document; try looking up some HTML/JS/CSS tutorials. The CSS has to be inside a `<style>` tag, and the JavaScript has to be in a `<script>` tag, and all that should be enclosed in a few other tags -- `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`

Comment: I did that and I just posted them separately.

Comment: Your question needs to include a [mcve] that shows how you are using the code and demonstrates the problem so other people can help with it. Also take a look at [ask] and the [help].